# Как исправить ошибку конструктора класса для получения данных из Firebase?

Tags: android, kotlin

Мне необходимо принимать данные сервера и затем они должны отправляться в MainActivity, плохо разбираюсь с конструкторами и классами, но код такой:

```
class Houses(_costV: String,  _locationV: String, _roomsV: String, _squareV: String,_image: String, _infoV: String,_pid: String,  _date: String,_time: String) {
private var costV: String
private var locationV: String
private var roomsV: String
private var squareV: String
private var image: String
private var infoV: String
private var pid: String
private var date: String
private var time: String
init {
    costV=_costV
    locationV=_locationV
    roomsV=_roomsV
    squareV=_squareV
    image=_image
    infoV=_infoV
    pid=_pid
    date=_date
    time=_time
}




fun getCostV(): String {
    return costV
}

fun setCostV(costV: String) {
    this.costV = costV
}

fun getLocationV(): String {
    return locationV
}

fun setLocationV(locationV: String) {
    this.locationV = locationV
}

fun getRoomsV(): String {
    return roomsV
}

fun setRoomsV(roomsV: String) {
    this.roomsV = roomsV
}

fun getSquareV(): String {
    return squareV
}

fun setSquareV(squareV: String) {
    this.squareV = squareV
}

fun getImage(): String {
    return image
}

fun setImage(image: String?) {
    this.image = image!!
}

fun getInfoV(): String {
    return infoV
}

fun setInfoV(infoV: String) {
    this.infoV = infoV
}

fun getPut(): String {
    return pid
}

fun setPut(pid: String) {
    this.pid = pid
}

fun getDate(): String {
    return date
}

fun setDate(date: String) {
    this.date = date
}

fun getTime(): String {
    return time
}

fun setTime(date: String) {
    this.time = date
}
```

}

Соответственно у меня вылетатет ошибка конструктора:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class ru.homebuy.neito.Model.Houses does not define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors are not stripped.
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:570)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(CustomClassMapper.java:563)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(CustomClassMapper.java:433)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:232)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(CustomClassMapper.java:80)
    at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:203)
    at com.firebase.ui.database.ClassSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(ClassSnapshotParser.java:29)
    at com.firebase.ui.database.ClassSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(ClassSnapshotParser.java:15)
    at com.firebase.ui.common.BaseCachingSnapshotParser.parseSnapshot(BaseCachingSnapshotParser.java:36)
    at com.firebase.ui.common.BaseObservableSnapshotArray.get(BaseObservableSnapshotArray.java:52)
    at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getItem(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:108)
    at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:148)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7254)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7337)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6194)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6460)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6300)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6296)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2330)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1631)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1591)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:668)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4309)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:4012)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:2028)
    at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:417)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1029)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:852)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:783)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1014)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7403)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
```

Помогите исправить эту проблему, пожалуйста..

Comment: В коде много лишнего, однако помочь должно добавление значения по умолчанию для каждого аргумента

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, по типу такого?  private var costV: String = ""
И что можно убрать лишнего?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, а, разобрался, действительно помогло, но меня всё же беспокоит, что можно убрать лишнее

Comment: Лишнее - все кроме конструктора)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, то есть даже геттеры и сеттеры не нужны?

Comment: Не нужны. Обращайтесь прямо к переменным из конструктора